# Admin UI for database entity administration and view?

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework

Is there any good auto-generation admin interface framework for database views?

I'm looking for an easy configurable framework that auto-detects my `@Entity` classes, connects to a database (eg `postgres`), and displays the content in some kind of managable admin servlet.

I know [`LightAdmin`](https://github.com/la-team/light-admin), which runs with `spring-boot` and goes in the right direction.

But unfortunately lacks major features (like the support of Composite Primary Keys, or configurable actions on the database rows - it provides view/edit/delete actions by default for each row which cannot be disabled at will!).

Is there any java alternative?

Answer (score 2):

[JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/), if you are ok with Java EE. There are addons that allow to select the web framework you want to use:

- [AngularJs](http://forge.jboss.org/addon/org.jboss.forge.addon:angularjs) ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg8Z7qHzpBA))
- [ExtJS](https://github.com/LemonSoftware/extjs-addon)

I have also used `LightAdmin`, but it turned out to be too unlimited and unfortunately no longer actively supported.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.openxava.org/ It generates the CRUD screens based on JPA Entity models.